# "undefined" when changing URL

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code, but I am not sure why I get "undefined".
I get(after clicking the link) "http://magiccards.info/query?q=**undefined**air elemental", but it should be "http://magiccards.info/query?q=air elemental", so without the word "undefined" and I tried replacing the "undefined" in the string but it did not help.

```
$(".englishMtg").click(function () {
    var currentHref = $(this).attr("href");
    if (currentHref.indexOf("http") == -1) {
        var changedLink = currentHref.replace("/TestPictures/").replace(".jpg");
        // # /TestPictures/air elemental , luftelementar.jpg
        var englishSearchString = "http://magiccards.info/query?q=" + changedLink.split(',')[0];
        $(this).attr("href", englishSearchString);
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
    }

    });
```

Need some help ....

Comment: are you trying to remove "/TestPictures/" and ".jpg" from the link?

Comment: yes, but there is always "/TestPictures/"

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for `replace` is missing. If you want to remove the occurrences, pass `''` as a replacement string: `replace('/TestPictures/', '').replace('.jpg', '')`

Comment: No sorry, I still get an undefined